# WireGuard's window opens every time at start up after macOS 11.6 update

Tags: macos, wireguard

I noticed that WireGuard's window opens every time at start up after macOS 11.6 update.

[image: screenshot]

This is annoying for me to close the window every time.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 10 hours since I posted this question, a moment ago, I received a notification of WireGuard's update (1.0.15).

This problem was fixed.